# hive sql get min and max values of multiple records

Tags: sql, hive

I have a query which results are

```
fruit           street             inventory            need      to_buy
banana          123                15                   99        22
apple           4                  32                   68        44
banana          789                01                   32        11
apple           9832               0                    99        94
apple           85                 839                  12        48
banana          832                77                   05        55
```

I want to get the minimum values for inventory, and need, and get the max to_buy value. but only have one record of each 'fruit'. the 'street' column is irrelevant and is not needed in the final result. The final result should look like

```
fruit            inventory(min)            need(min)      to_buy(max)
banana           01                        05             55
apple            0                         12             94
```

Also the initial records may not be ordered at first so there are more 'fruits' inserted at random  How can i achieve the desired result above?

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`, `MIN()`, `MAX()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT MIN(inventory), MIN(need), MAX(to_buy)
FROM tableName
GROUP BY fruits
```

Answer (score 0):

This one should work:

```
SELECT fruits, MIN(inventory), MIN(need), MAX(to_buy)
FROM <table_name>
GROUP BY fruits
```