# Functions LEAST, GREATEST not considering NULL

Tags: sql, oracle, hive

Can you please tell me how to make the least and greatest function output the minimum and maximum date, not taking into account NULL values.

| a | b | c | d | e | f |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 | 2020-02-03 | NULL | NULL | 2020-10-13 | NULL |

result

| least | greatest |
| --- | --- |
| 2020-02-03 | 2021-01-01 |

Comment: You have one record with 6 columns?

Comment: After joining several tables there are several columns with dates from which you need to find the maximum and minimum but do not consider NULL.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50239510/hive-sql-get-min-and-max-values-of-multiple-records

Comment: Are columns of type STRING or DATE?

Comment: All values in ``least`` should be surrounded by [``coalesce(..., large value)``](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_coalesce.asp) and in ``greatest`` [``coalesce (..., small value)``](https://laurentschneider.com/wordpress/2008/01/what-is-the-lowest-and-highest-possible-date-in-oracle.html). Is it applicable in your case?

Answer (score -1):

You can use the functions `MIN()` and `MAX()` for the respective values. As for ignoring NULL values, just add that to the where part of your query, e.g:

```
SELECT MIN(t.day) AS least, MAX(t.day) AS greatest
FROM yourTable AS t
WHERE t.day IS NOT NULL
```

Of course, you still need to adapt that statement to your specific case.